# Is ColdFusion's isSafeHTML() documentation wrong everywhere?

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-11, coldfusion-2016

I have been trying to use `isSafeHTML()` to tell users whether the HTML they have submitted is allowed or not. The documentation at both [CFDocs.org](https://cfdocs.org/issafehtml) and [Adobe.com](https://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/cfml-reference/coldfusion-functions/functions-in-k/issafehtml.html) show the function requires three parameters: `inputString, policyFile, throwOnError`. However, when I supply all three parameters, I get an error saying it only accepts 1 or 2 parameters.

After some testing, I have come to the conclusion that `throwOnError` is not a valid parameter for this function. Can anyone else confirm this? If so, is there any way to update the documentation so others do not run into the same issue?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are correct, I just tested it on ColdFusion 2016 update 2 (2016,0,02,299200) and it threw:

> Parameter validation error for the ISSAFEHTML function. 
>   The function accepts 1 to 2 parameters.

Using this code:

```
<cfoutput>
#isSafeHTML("html", server.coldfusion.rootdir & "/lib/antisamy-basic.xml", true)#
</cfoutput>
```

I have updated the cfdocs.org site to remove the `throwOnError` argument. For future reference you can fix docs on cfdocs.org by clicking on the Edit button, or if you just want to point out an issue you can click on the Issue button.

For Adobe docs, you can file a bug report here: https://bugbase.adobe.com/

Comment: BTW I pinged someone at adobe responsible for documentation and they said it shold be fixed tomorrow on their end

Comment: Adobe has updated the docs, thanks for pointing this out: https://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/cfml-reference/coldfusion-functions/functions-in-k/issafehtml.html